# Does anyone know of a flash/flex library which can animate a route path on a map?

Tags: flash, apache-flex, actionscript-3, mapping

I would like to do something like this - http://www.ammap.com/examples/flight_routes but have the individual lines animate and show progress along a route. It needs to be a 'real' map so that I can feed in LAT/Longs for for the polylines.

This is also a similar effect - http://googlemapsmania.blogspot.com/2010/12/indiana-jones-map-effect.html but I don't need the map panning.

I am aware of the google maps api for Flash but there doesn't seem to be any animation other than panning.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, this isn't php, it probably isn't available.

In case I am right, to start it manually, use one of the tweening engines available for flash. Which one you choose is up to you. It should make it ultra easy to do it. Lat/Long conversion to pixels should be easy as well once you center the map.

[tween engines google search](http://www.google.com/search?q=tweening%20engine%20flash)

Good luck.